# How to convert Javascript Anonymous Function to Java maybe with switch?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, variables, anonymous-function

Here is the javascript code below with a few anonymous inner functions linked to it seems 2 array indexes for each switch, they seem to return some value too, but I have no idea where they are returning to the `memoryReadJumpCompile()` function or both those array index's.

Most likely they are reuturning to the actual array indexes and by the function name Compile it seems that everytime you call any of those array indexes they will re-evaluate the function linked to them with some new result still don't know where the result is stored if the actual index's hold functions, my best guess is the actual array indexes are like function names and they are returned by another piece of code where-ever else the index's are called somewhere in code but lets say the first 2 example array indexes.

```
this.memoryHighReader[0] = this.memoryReader[0xFF00]
```

So they both become the same thing, I found that it gets processed in the instruction executor like so

```
case 242:
    a.registerA = a.memoryHighReader[a.registerC](a, a.registerC);
    break;
```

```
  GameBoyCore.prototype.memoryReadJumpCompile = function () {
    //...
    else if (index >= 0xFF00) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0xFF00:
          //JOYPAD:
          this.memoryHighReader[0] = this.memoryReader[0xFF00] = function (parentObj, address) {
            return 0xC0 | parentObj.memory[0xFF00];  //Top nibble returns as set.
          }
          break;
        case 0xFF01:
          //SB
          this.memoryHighReader[0x01] = this.memoryReader[0xFF01] = function (parentObj, address) {
            return (parentObj.memory[0xFF02] < 0x80) ? parentObj.memory[0xFF01] : 0xFF;
          }
          break;
        case 0xFF02:
          //SC
          if (this.cGBC) {
            this.memoryHighReader[0x02] = this.memoryReader[0xFF02] = function (parentObj, address) {
              return ((parentObj.serialTimer <= 0) ? 0x7C : 0xFC) | parentObj.memory[0xFF02];
            }
          }
          else {
            this.memoryHighReader[0x02] = this.memoryReader[0xFF02] = function (parentObj, address) {
              return ((parentObj.serialTimer <= 0) ? 0x7E : 0xFE) | parentObj.memory[0xFF02];
            }
          }
          break;
    }
  }
```

The above javascript is nearly like Java but I can't understand how to convert the `function(parentObj, address) {...}` in the `memoryReadJumpCompile` whats the easiest way to convert this to Java without using Interfaces either. I would like to use a `switch()`

Here is what I have so far in Java (it doesn't use hexadecimal letters because I used Minified JavaScript version when I started converting)

```
public void memoryReadJumpCompile() {
  for (var a = 0; a <= 65535; a++) {
    if (a < 16384) {
      this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
    } else {
      if (a < 32768) {
        this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadROM;
      } else {
        if (a < 38912) {
          this.memoryReader[a] = (this.cGBC) ? this.VRAMDATAReadCGBCPU : this.VRAMDATAReadDMGCPU;
        } else {
          if (a < 40960) {
            this.memoryReader[a] = (this.cGBC) ? this.VRAMCHRReadCGBCPU : this.VRAMCHRReadDMGCPU;
          } else {
            if (a >= 40960 && a < 49152) {
              if ((this.numRAMBanks == 1 / 16 && a < 41472) || this.numRAMBanks >= 1) {
                if (this.cMBC7) {
                  this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadMBC7;
                } else {
                  if (!this.cMBC3) {
                    this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadMBC;
                  } else {
                    this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadMBC3;
                  }
                }
              } else {
                this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
              }
            } else {
              if (a >= 49152 && a < 57344) {
                if (!this.cGBC || a < 53248) {
                  this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                } else {
                  this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadGBCMemory;
                }
              } else {
                if (a >= 57344 && a < 65024) {
                  if (!this.cGBC || a < 61440) {
                    this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadECHONormal;
                  } else {
                    this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadECHOGBCMemory;
                  }
                } else {
                  if (a < 65184) {
                    this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadOAM;
                  } else {
                    if (this.cGBC && a >= 65184 && a < 65280) {
                      this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                    } else {
                      if (a >= 65280) {
                        switch (a) {
                        case 65280:
                          this.memoryHighReader[0] = this.memoryReader[65280] = function(c, b) {
                            return 192 | c.memory[65280];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65281:
                          this.memoryHighReader[1] = this.memoryReader[65281] = function(c, b) {
                            return (c.memory[65282] < 128) ? c.memory[65281] : 255;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65282:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[2] = this.memoryReader[65282] = function(c, b) {
                              return ((c.serialTimer <= 0) ? 124 : 252) | c.memory[65282];
                            }
                          } else {
                            this.memoryHighReader[2] = this.memoryReader[65282] = function(c, b) {
                              return ((c.serialTimer <= 0) ? 126 : 254) | c.memory[65282];
                            }
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65283:
                          this.memoryHighReader[3] = this.memoryReader[65283] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65284:
                          this.memoryHighReader[4] = this.memoryReader[65284] = function(c, b) {
                            c.memory[65284] = (c.memory[65284] + (c.DIVTicks >> 8)) & 255;
                            c.DIVTicks &= 255;
                            return c.memory[65284];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65285:
                        case 65286:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65287:
                          this.memoryHighReader[7] = this.memoryReader[65287] = function(c, b) {
                            return 248 | c.memory[65287];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65288:
                        case 65289:
                        case 65290:
                        case 65291:
                        case 65292:
                        case 65293:
                        case 65294:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65295:
                          this.memoryHighReader[15] = this.memoryReader[65295] = function(c, b) {
                            return 224 | c.interruptsRequested;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65296:
                          this.memoryHighReader[16] = this.memoryReader[65296] = function(c, b) {
                            return 128 | c.memory[65296];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65297:
                          this.memoryHighReader[17] = this.memoryReader[65297] = function(c, b) {
                            return 63 | c.memory[65297];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65298:
                          this.memoryHighReader[18] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[65298] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65299:
                          this.memoryHighReader[19] = this.memoryReader[65299] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65300:
                          this.memoryHighReader[20] = this.memoryReader[65300] = function(c, b) {
                            return 191 | c.memory[65300];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65301:
                          this.memoryHighReader[21] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          this.memoryReader[65301] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65302:
                          this.memoryHighReader[22] = this.memoryReader[65302] = function(c, b) {
                            return 63 | c.memory[65302];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65303:
                          this.memoryHighReader[23] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[65303] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65304:
                          this.memoryHighReader[24] = this.memoryReader[65304] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65305:
                          this.memoryHighReader[25] = this.memoryReader[65305] = function(c, b) {
                            return 191 | c.memory[65305];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65306:
                          this.memoryHighReader[26] = this.memoryReader[65306] = function(c, b) {
                            return 127 | c.memory[65306];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65307:
                          this.memoryHighReader[27] = this.memoryReader[65307] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65308:
                          this.memoryHighReader[28] = this.memoryReader[65308] = function(c, b) {
                            return 159 | c.memory[65308];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65309:
                          this.memoryHighReader[29] = this.memoryReader[65309] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65310:
                          this.memoryHighReader[30] = this.memoryReader[65310] = function(c, b) {
                            return 191 | c.memory[65310];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65311:
                        case 65312:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65313:
                        case 65314:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65315:
                          this.memoryHighReader[35] = this.memoryReader[65315] = function(c, b) {
                            return 191 | c.memory[65315];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65316:
                        case 65317:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65318:
                          this.memoryHighReader[38] = this.memoryReader[65318] = function(c, b) {
                            c.audioJIT();
                            return 112 | c.memory[65318];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65319:
                        case 65320:
                        case 65321:
                        case 65322:
                        case 65323:
                        case 65324:
                        case 65325:
                        case 65326:
                        case 65327:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65328:
                        case 65329:
                        case 65330:
                        case 65331:
                        case 65332:
                        case 65333:
                        case 65334:
                        case 65335:
                        case 65336:
                        case 65337:
                        case 65338:
                        case 65339:
                        case 65340:
                        case 65341:
                        case 65342:
                        case 65343:
                          this.memoryReader[a] = function(c, b) {
                            return (c.channel3canPlay) ? c.memory[65280 | (c.channel3lastSampleLookup >> 1)] : c.memory[b];
                          };
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = function(c, b) {
                            return (c.channel3canPlay) ? c.memory[65280 | (c.channel3lastSampleLookup >> 1)] : c.memory[65280 | b];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65344:
                          this.memoryHighReader[64] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[65344] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65345:
                          this.memoryHighReader[65] = this.memoryReader[65345] = function(c, b) {
                            return 128 | c.memory[65345] | c.modeSTAT;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65346:
                          this.memoryHighReader[66] = this.memoryReader[65346] = function(c, b) {
                            return c.backgroundY;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65347:
                          this.memoryHighReader[67] = this.memoryReader[65347] = function(c, b) {
                            return c.backgroundX;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65348:
                          this.memoryHighReader[68] = this.memoryReader[65348] = function(c, b) {
                            return ((c.LCDisOn) ? c.memory[65348] : 0);
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65349:
                        case 65350:
                        case 65351:
                        case 65352:
                        case 65353:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65354:
                          this.memoryHighReader[74] = this.memoryReader[65354] = function(c, b) {
                            return c.windowY;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65355:
                          this.memoryHighReader[75] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[65355] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65356:
                          this.memoryHighReader[76] = this.memoryReader[65356] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65357:
                          this.memoryHighReader[77] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[65357] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65358:
                          this.memoryHighReader[78] = this.memoryReader[65358] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65359:
                          this.memoryHighReader[79] = this.memoryReader[65359] = function(c, b) {
                            return c.currVRAMBank;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65360:
                        case 65361:
                        case 65362:
                        case 65363:
                        case 65364:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65365:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[85] = this.memoryReader[65365] = function(c, b) {
                              if (!c.LCDisOn && c.hdmaRunning) {
                                c.DMAWrite((c.memory[65365] & 127) + 1);
                                c.memory[65365] = 255;
                                c.hdmaRunning = false;
                              }
                              return c.memory[65365];
                            }
                          } else {
                            this.memoryReader[65365] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                            this.memoryHighReader[85] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65366:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[86] = this.memoryReader[65366] = function(c, b) {
                              return 60 | ((c.memory[65366] >= 192) ? (2 | (c.memory[65366] & 193)) : (c.memory[65366] & 195));
                            }
                          } else {
                            this.memoryReader[65366] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                            this.memoryHighReader[86] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65367:
                        case 65368:
                        case 65369:
                        case 65370:
                        case 65371:
                        case 65372:
                        case 65373:
                        case 65374:
                        case 65375:
                        case 65376:
                        case 65377:
                        case 65378:
                        case 65379:
                        case 65380:
                        case 65381:
                        case 65382:
                        case 65383:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65384:
                        case 65385:
                        case 65386:
                        case 65387:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65388:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[108] = this.memoryReader[65388] = function(c, b) {
                              return 254 | c.memory[65388];
                            }
                          } else {
                            this.memoryHighReader[108] = this.memoryReader[65388] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65389:
                        case 65390:
                        case 65391:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65392:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[112] = this.memoryReader[65392] = function(c, b) {
                              return 64 | c.memory[65392];
                            }
                          } else {
                            this.memoryHighReader[112] = this.memoryReader[65392] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65393:
                          this.memoryHighReader[113] = this.memoryReader[65393] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65394:
                        case 65395:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          break;
                        case 65396:
                          if (this.cGBC) {
                            this.memoryHighReader[116] = this.memoryReader[65396] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          } else {
                            this.memoryHighReader[116] = this.memoryReader[65396] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          }
                          break;
                        case 65397:
                          this.memoryHighReader[117] = this.memoryReader[65397] = function(c, b) {
                            return 143 | c.memory[65397];
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65398:
                        case 65399:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = function(c, b) {
                            return 0;
                          };
                          break;
                        case 65400:
                        case 65401:
                        case 65402:
                        case 65403:
                        case 65404:
                        case 65405:
                        case 65406:
                        case 65407:
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                          break;
                        case 65535:
                          this.memoryHighReader[255] = this.memoryReader[65535] = function(c, b) {
                            return c.interruptsEnabled;
                          };
                          break;
                        default:
                          this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadNormal;
                          this.memoryHighReader[a & 255] = this.memoryHighReadNormal;
                        }
                      } else {
                        this.memoryReader[a] = this.memoryReadBAD;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started splitting the `memoryReadJumpCompile` into combining them into memoryHighRead and memoryRead functions. Takes about 1 hour per function.

Here is a example of the `memoryReader`, I completed them all 4 of them (memoryRead/memoryReadHigh/memoryWrite/memoryWriteHigh), not sure if it works, still over 100 errors! haha long way to go.

```
public long memoryReader(address) {
    //return memoryReader[address](this, address);
    if (address < 16384) {
        return memoryReadNormal(address);
    } else if (address < 32768) {
        return memoryReadROM(address);
    } else if (address < 38912) {
        return (cGBC) ? VRAMDATAReadCGBCPU(address) : VRAMDATAReadDMGCPU(address);
    } else if (address < 40960) {
        return (cGBC) ? VRAMCHRReadCGBCPU(address) : VRAMCHRReadDMGCPU(address);
    } else if (address >= 40960 && address < 49152) {
        if ((numRAMBanks == 1 / 16 && address < 41472) || numRAMBanks >= 1) {
            if (cMBC7) {
                return memoryReadMBC7(address);
            } else if (!cMBC3) {
                return memoryReadMBC(address);
            } else {
                return memoryReadMBC3(address);
            }
        } else {
            return memoryReadBAD();
        }
    } else if (address >= 49152 && address < 57344) {
        if (!cGBC || address < 53248) {
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
        } else {
            return memoryReadGBCMemory(address);
        }
    } else if (address >= 57344 && address < 65024) {
        if (!cGBC || address < 61440) {
            return memoryReadECHONormal(address);
        } else {
            return memoryReadECHOGBCMemory(address);
        }
    } else if (address < 65184) {
        return memoryReadOAM(address);
    } else if (cGBC && address >= 65184 && address < 65280) {
        return memoryReadNormal(address);
    } else if (address >= 65280) {
        switch (address) {
        case 65280:
            return 192 | memory[65280];
            break;
        case 65281:
            return (memory[65282] < 128) ? memory[65281] : 255;
            break;
        case 65282:
            if (cGBC) {
                return ((serialTimer <= 0) ? 124 : 252) | memory[65282];
            } else {
                return ((serialTimer <= 0) ? 126 : 254) | memory[65282];
            }
            break;
        case 65283:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65284:
            memory[65284] = (memory[65284] + (DIVTicks >> 8)) & 255;
            DIVTicks &= 255;
            return memory[65284];
            break;
        case 65285:
        case 65286:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65287:
            return 248 | memory[65287];
            break;
        case 65288:
        case 65289:
        case 65290:
        case 65291:
        case 65292:
        case 65293:
        case 65294:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65295:
            return 224 | interruptsRequested;
            break;
        case 65296:
            return 128 | memory[65296];
            break;
        case 65297:
            return 63 | memory[65297];
            break;
        case 65298:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65299:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65300:
            return 191 | memory[65300];
            break;
        case 65301:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65302:
            return 63 | memory[65302];
            break;
        case 65303:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65304:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65305:
            return 191 | memory[65305];
            break;
        case 65306:
            return 127 | memory[65306];
            break;
        case 65307:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65308:
            return 159 | memory[65308];
            break;
        case 65309:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65310:
            return 191 | memory[65310];
            break;
        case 65311:
        case 65312:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65313:
        case 65314:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65315:
            return 191 | memory[65315];
            break;
        case 65316:
        case 65317:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65318:
            c.audioJIT();
            return 112 | memory[65318];
            break;
        case 65319:
        case 65320:
        case 65321:
        case 65322:
        case 65323:
        case 65324:
        case 65325:
        case 65326:
        case 65327:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65328:
        case 65329:
        case 65330:
        case 65331:
        case 65332:
        case 65333:
        case 65334:
        case 65335:
        case 65336:
        case 65337:
        case 65338:
        case 65339:
        case 65340:
        case 65341:
        case 65342:
        case 65343:
            return (channel3canPlay) ? memory[65280 | (channel3lastSampleLookup >> 1)] : memory[address];
            break;
        case 65344:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65345:
            return 128 | memory[65345] | modeSTAT;
            break;
        case 65346:
            return backgroundY;
            break;
        case 65347:
            return backgroundX;
            break;
        case 65348:
            return ((LCDisOn) ? memory[65348] : 0);
            break;
        case 65349:
        case 65350:
        case 65351:
        case 65352:
        case 65353:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65354:
            return windowY;
            break;
        case 65355:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65356:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65357:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65358:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65359:
            return currVRAMBank;
            break;
        case 65360:
        case 65361:
        case 65362:
        case 65363:
        case 65364:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65365:
            if (cGBC) {
                if (!LCDisOn && hdmaRunning) {
                    DMAWrite((memory[65365] & 127) + 1);
                    memory[65365] = 255;
                    hdmaRunning = false;
                }
                return memory[65365];
            } else {
                return memoryReadNormal(address);
            }
            break;
        case 65366:
            if (cGBC) {
                return 60 | ((memory[65366] >= 192) ? (2 | (memory[65366] & 193)) : (memory[65366] & 195));
            } else {
                return memoryReadNormal(address);
            }
            break;
        case 65367:
        case 65368:
        case 65369:
        case 65370:
        case 65371:
        case 65372:
        case 65373:
        case 65374:
        case 65375:
        case 65376:
        case 65377:
        case 65378:
        case 65379:
        case 65380:
        case 65381:
        case 65382:
        case 65383:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65384:
        case 65385:
        case 65386:
        case 65387:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65388:
            if (cGBC) {
                return 254 | memory[65388];
            } else {
                return memoryReadBAD();
            }
            break;
        case 65389:
        case 65390:
        case 65391:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65392:
            if (cGBC) {
                return 64 | memory[65392];
            } else {
                return memoryReadBAD();
            }
            break;
        case 65393:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65394:
        case 65395:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
            break;
        case 65396:
            if (cGBC) {
                return memoryReadNormal(address);
            } else {
                return memoryReadBAD();
            }
            break;
        case 65397:
            return 143 | memory[65397];
            break;
        case 65398:
        case 65399:
            return 0;
            break;
        case 65400:
        case 65401:
        case 65402:
        case 65403:
        case 65404:
        case 65405:
        case 65406:
        case 65407:
            return memoryReadBAD();
            break;
        case 65535:
            return interruptsEnabled;
            break;
        default:
            return memoryReadNormal(address);
        }
    } else {
        return memoryReadBAD();
    }
}
```