# How to translate this javascript code which uses array of functions binded and recursively called inside

Tags: java, javascript, recursion, translate

It's written in Javascript I already started translating it to Java, but got stuck don't see any other way to do this.

I would like to make `initializeLCDController` to like `getLINECONTROL(int index)` not to use the function binded arrays method.

```
public void initializeLCDController() {
    long a = 0;
    while (a < 154) {
        if (a < 143) {
            LINECONTROL[a] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks < 80) {
                    scanLineMode2();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 252) {
                    scanLineMode3();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 456) {
                    scanLineMode0();
                } else {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    if (STATTracker != 3) {
                        if (STATTracker != 2) {
                            if (STATTracker == 0 && mode2TriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            }
                            incrementScanLineQueue();
                        }
                        if (hdmaRunning) {
                            executeHDMA();
                        }
                        if (mode0TriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    actualScanLine = ++memory[65348];
                    if (actualScanLine == memory[65349]) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    checkIRQMatching();
                    STATTracker = 0;
                    modeSTAT = 2;
                    LINECONTROL[actualScanLine]();
                }
            }
        } else if (a == 143) {
            LINECONTROL[143] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks < 80) {
                    scanLineMode2();
                } else if (b.LCDTicks < 252) {
                    scanLineMode3();
                } else if (b.LCDTicks < 456) {
                    scanLineMode0();
                } else {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    if (STATTracker != 3) {
                        if (STATTracker != 2) {
                            if (STATTracker == 0 && mode2TriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            }
                            incrementScanLineQueue();
                        }
                        if (hdmaRunning) {
                            executeHDMA();
                        }
                        if (mode0TriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    actualScanLine = b.memory[65348] = 144;
                    if (memory[65349] == 144) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    STATTracker = 0;
                    modeSTAT = 1;
                    interruptsRequested |= (mode1TriggerSTAT) ? 3 : 1;
                    checkIRQMatching();
                    if (drewBlank == 0) {
                        if (totalLinesPassed < 144 || (totalLinesPassed == 144 && midScanlineOffset > -1)) {
                            graphicsJITVBlank();
                            prepareFrame();
                        }
                    } else {
                        --drewBlank;
                    }
                    LINECONTROL[144]();
                }
            }
        } else if (a < 153) {
            LINECONTROL[a] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks >= 456) {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    actualScanLine = ++memory[65348];
                    if (actualScanLine == memory[65349]) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            checkIRQMatching();
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    LINECONTROL[actualScanLine]();
                }
            }
        } else {
            LINECONTROL[153] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks >= 8) {
                    if (STATTracker != 4 && memory[65348] == 153) {
                        memory[65348] = 0;
                        if (memory[65349] == 0) {
                            memory[65345] |= 4;
                            if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                                checkIRQMatching();
                            }
                        } else {
                            memory[65345] &= 123;
                        }
                        STATTracker = 4;
                    }
                    if (LCDTicks >= 456) {
                        LCDTicks -= 456;
                        STATTracker = actualScanLine = 0;
                        LINECONTROL[0]();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ++a;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot to ask for..

Comment: Any kind of tip would help I could complete it myself just need a to get started up with.

Comment: Seems to have 2 hard coded array indexes the rest are computed from while loop

Comment: This blob of nested if-statements and inconsistent indentation is extremely hard to read and understand. Improve your question by writing a minimal example of what you are trying to do and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I indented it using JSBeautifier. I don't want the if statements code touched or changed at all I just want to get rid of the function(b) { .. } and LINECONTROL array that's it.

Comment: What is `LINECONTROL`? The issue with blindly trying to translate code from one language to another is that you might end up trying to translate something that has no counterpart in the target language (try writing a classic for-loop in a functional language). Explain what you are trying to accomplish; take a step back to a higher level of abstraction. What does the code do? How do you expect it to work in Java? Edit: A minimal example will *still* improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: The LINECONTROL is a array of `function() {}` for each index in javascript. I can't create array's of function pointers in Java but I can convert the array's of function into a switch() in certain situations like my previous question I asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494343/how-to-convert-javascript-anonymous-function-to-java-maybe-with-switch This one is similar but this requires Recursion I believe. Where you see lines like this `b.LINECONTROL[b.actualScanLine](b)` it's obviously means it calling the array at index actualScanLine then calls the function with argument b.

Comment: cleaned up the code a little, still can't convert it to Java seems this code runs in another method after the `initializeLCDController()` called `executeIteration()` where the virtual CPU gets processed. https://github.com/grantgalitz/GameBoy-Online/blob/master/js/GameBoyCore.js